# Understanding code that sums prime factors of array values?

Tags: php, arrays

So the function evaluates a each value in an array, tests divisibility with a prime number starting with 2 (and then 3, 5 etc) and if it's a factor of one or more elements, add them up. And then print the factors and the sum of all their dividends. So for example:

> ```
> [12, 15, 18] // returns [ [2, 30], [3, 45], [5, 15] ];
> ```

Here is the function:

```
function sumOfDivided($lst) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($lst as $number) {
        for ($i = 2; $i <= abs($number); $i++) {
            if ($number % $i == 0) {
                $prime = true;
                for ($j = 2; $j < $i; $j++) {
                    if ($i % $j == 0) {
                        $prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($prime) {
                    if(isset($result[$i])) {
                        $result[$i] += $number;
                    } else {
                        $result[$i] = $number;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    ksort($result);
    return array_map(function($k, $v){
        return [$k, $v];
    }, array_keys($result), array_values($result));
}
```

If we use 2 for `$number` it appears that since 2 is less than `abs($number)` and it equals 0 when divided by 12 `$prime` is set to **true**. And then in the next for loop using `$j` it wouldn't evaluate because 2 is not less than 2.

So then we go to `if($prime)` and set `$result[$i] += $number` but why do we set the second index of the array to 12? Shouldn't we be starting with `$result[0]`?

Also won't the `foreach()` loop go to 15 next? After evaluating 12 as described above. This function works well I just don't quite get it.

Comment: Didn't you ask this twice [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467818/) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465581)

Comment: Yes I did, but hopefully including some relevant code will give better insight. I really want to learn.

Comment: What exactly can do you mean by *I just don't quite get it* as it will help in explaining a specific problem.

Comment: @NigelRen: So for `$i = 2` it would be set to `true` and then since `$result[$i]` is not set it's set to `$result[2]` since `$i` starts at 2. Why is the first index (0) not used?

Comment: 2 is not a sequential index but rather the prime number which is set as an associative key for $result.

Comment: @nice_dev: Ok that makes total sense, thanks for clarifying. I got stuck on the last chunk. If you feel like answering I'll accept.

Comment: @nice_dev: I guess I'm also confused about how it's checking for prime. That part is very concise but hard ot understand.

Comment: Prime numbers have only 1 and themselves as factors. So, if $i is divisible by $j apart from 1 and number itself, then the $prime flag is changed to false.